# What does 'request-response' mode in 'routing options' Oracle Service Bus action mean?

Tags: osb

I am using `Service Callout` to invoke external web services and when I add the action `routing options` the `mode` parameter accepts two values:

- request
- request-response

But I don´t know which is the difference and the official documentation states nothing about these values http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/admin.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#OSBAG1123

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`request/response` mode means you send a message and wait for a response via the same channel.

`request` mode means you send a message and do not expect a response.

I think there's also a mode where you send the request on one channel and expect the response via another channel (i.e. asynchronous messaging via a pair of JMS queues or whatever)